How to apply filter to aggregation operations in mongodb template
I'm using spring data mongodb 4.3.6 version
And the filter does not work in the following code.
// filter
    ArrayOperators.Filter filter = ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("messages")
        .as("message")
        .by(ComparisonOperators.Gt.valueOf("message._id").greaterThanValue(new ObjectId(startObjectId))); 
        // Apply only 1 condition due to testing

    
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("roomId").is(roomId)),
        Aggregation.project("messages").and(filter)
    );

    RoomMessage roomMsg = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "room_msg", RoomMessage.class).getUniqueMappedResult();

    for (Message roomMessage : roomMsg.getMessageList()) {
        System.out.println("roomMessage.getContent() = " + roomMessage.getContent());
    }

▲ The match operation works, but the filter doesn't  work
Status of the actual collection document:
[
{
roomId: 1
messages: [ {_id: , content: , .. } ]
},

{
roomId: 2
messages: [ {_id: , content: , .. } ]
}
.
.
]

I only want to get messages that meet the conditions in the messages field
The query I would like to apply are as follows:
db.room_msg.aggregate([
  { $match: { roomId: 1 } },
  { $project: { 
      messages: { 
        $filter: {
          input: "$messages",
          as: "message",
          cond: { 
            $and: [
              { $gt: [ "$$message._id", ObjectId("67622277a31d5f6390658340") ] },
              { $lt: [ "$$message._id", ObjectId("67622277a31d5f6390658345") ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])


